# How to push new key and value in JSON array in mongodb?

Tags: json, mongodb

How can I push new key and value in JSON array?

I tried I used push keyword in update query but I got a different output. I used:

```
 db.users.updateOne({"name":"viki"},{$push{"address.district":"thambaram"}})
```

I have this document:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58934f10c7592b1494fd9a4d"), "name" : "viki", "age" : 100, "subject" : [ "c", "node.js", "java" ], "address" : { "city" : "chennai", "state" : "tamilnadu", "pincode" : "123" } }
```

I want to add `"district":"thambaram"` in address json array

I need like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58934f10c7592b1494fd9a4d"), "name" : "viki", "age" : 100, "subject" : [ "c", "node.js", "java" ], "address" : { "city" : "chennai", "state" : "tamilnadu", "pincode" : "123","district":"thambaram"} }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: You can not use `$push` operator because this is not an array. You can use simple nested object property assignment.

Comment: i got this output:              { "_id" : ObjectId("58934f10c7592b1494fd9a4d"), "name" : "viki", "age" : 100, "subject" : [ "c", "node.js", "java" ], "address" : { "city" : "chennai", "state" : "tamilnadu", "pincode" : "123", "district" : [ "thambaram" ] } }            but I need { "_id" : ObjectId("58934f10c7592b1494fd9a4d"), "name" : "viki", "age" : 100, "subject" : [ "c", "node.js", "java" ], "address" : { "city" : "chennai", "state" : "tamilnadu", "pincode" : "123","district":"thambaram"} }

Comment: can you give me a code

Comment: See my answer. It will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks bro It works perfectly.but i have small doubt Normally,.we can use $set keyword when update the array only but now we add new elements using this keyword?

Comment: Kindly accept my answer if it helped you. And we need to use push to add a new element to array. Your's was not an array.

Comment: Please do not add long strings of code or JSON into comments - they are fairly unreadable. Instead, add them into your question [by editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43785742/edit) and use the formatting tools provided. Thanks.

Comment: How did you get on with @FallAndLearn's answer? If that was the solution, please accept it. Let us know if you do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$set`

```
db.users.updateOne({"name":"viki"},{$set:{"address.district":"thambaram"}})
```

This should work.

The `$push` operator appends a specified value to an array. In your case you should use `$set`